# Where is the grouping & list of applications defined for PCManFM-Qt?

Tags: pcmanfm

**WHAT I DO:**

PCManFM-Qt > Open With ... > Other Applications
Choose Application > Installed Applications

**WHAT IT DOES:**

Displays a blank box.

[image]

**WHAT I EXPECT:**

I expect to see a tree of applications grouped by type.

When I use Dolphin it works as expected.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a bugreport. https://github.com/lxqt/pcmanfm-qt/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing  `lxmenu-data`

```
sudo apt install lxmenu-data pcmanfm-qt
```

and reboot corrected the problem.

per instruction from [github.com/lxqt/pcmanfm-qt bug report](https://github.com/lxqt/pcmanfm-qt/issues/1791) as suggested by [lpor Sircer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/182562/ipor-sircer)

[image: PCManFM-Qt with apps listed]